# "Handler method not accessible" error in FXML (works only if I make method with "Event" or "ActionEvent" parameter)

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, keyevent, fxml

I want to call handler method when any key on keyboard is pressed, and then get pressed key character. So I wrote this line for button in fxml file:

```
<Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="90.0" onKeyPressed="#handleButton" text="Test!" />
```

When any key is pressed, this should call handleButton method in controller class and pass KeyEvent parameter to it. So I wrote this method inside it:

```
@FXML
private void handleButton(KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event);
}
```

In the fxml file NetBeans shows error "Handler method is not accessible. Make public, or annotate with @FXML.", which I've already done.

As soon as I change from `private void handleButton(KeyEvent event)` to `private void handleButton(Event event)` NetBeans stops showing error and app works.

On [this](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11089402#11089402) page I found answer, which uses onKeyPressed exactly the same as I do, so I'm really confused why it isn't working in my case.

Thanks for your help,

Vid

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably imported wrong `KeyEvent`. It must be `javafx.​scene.​input.KeyEvent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) now it works. I was using auto import (CTRL-SHIFT-I) and forgot to check out.

Comment: Saved me a day.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click with the mouse on your `file.FXML` and choose from options `make controller` and automatically the problem will be resolved and this error will be gone.